# Is the Smarty function register_modifier() necessary?

Tags: smarty

My code:

**index.php**

```
function smarty_function_eightball($params, $smarty)
{
    $answers = array('Да',
                     'Нет',
                     'Никоим образом',
                     'Перспектива так себе...',
                     'Спросите позже',
                     'Все может быть');

    $result = array_rand($answers);
    return $answers[$result];
}
function smarty_modifier_capitalize($string)
{
    return ucwords($string);
}
```

**index.tpl**

```
{eightball|capitalize}
```

The code works fine. Why then would I need the function `register_modifier()`?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not using register_modifier() in this example.

Answer (score 1):

That is to bind PHP functions as Smarty variable modifiers. 
It has no use to bind functions that already exist in Smarty of course.

Since capitalize is already build into Smarty, {eightball|capitalize} works without using register_modifier().